# SEQUELIZE: Order by COUNT of associated model

Tags: javascript, sql, json, postgresql, sequelize.js

I currently have a query that returns an array of `Projects` and it also includes a model named `Campaign`. My `Campaign` model has a column called `status` which is either `ACTIVE` or `PAUSED`. For each `Project` in my array, I want to receive a count of all the `ACTIVE` campaigns that it contains and then I want to order my `Projects` array in descending order according to that count.

In other words, I want all the `Projects` with `ACTIVE` campaigns to appear at the top of the array that I receive when my query is completed.

```
const query = { id: { $in: ids } };

models.Project.findAndCountAll({
  where: query,
  limit: PROJECT_PAGE_SIZE,
  offset: (PROJECT_PAGE_SIZE * (pageNumber - 1)),
  distinct: true,
  attributes: Object.keys(models.Project.attributes).concat([
    [sequelize.literal('(SELECT SUM("strategies_data"."spend") FROM "strategies_data" WHERE "strategies_data"."project_id" = "Project"."id")'),
      'total_spend'],
    [sequelize.literal('(SELECT SUM("strategies_data"."impressions") FROM "strategies_data" WHERE "strategies_data"."project_id" = "Project"."id")'),
      'total_impressions'],
  ]),
  include: [{
    model: models.Campaign,
    attributes: ['id', 'name', 'status'],
    include: [{ model: models.Channel }, { model: models.Strategy }],
  }],
})
```

Comment: What are the results that you're currently getting?

Comment: I'm currently receiving an array of Projects and each project hasMany campaigns. I want to COUNT all the campaigns with an active status and order my projects according to that count.